# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is a finite group. Let $S=\{Hx|x\in G\}$. Prove $Stab(Hx) = x^{-1}Hx$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is a finite group. Let $S=\{Hx|x\in G\}$. Prove Stabilizer of $Hx$ is conjugate of $H$ by $x$, i.e. $Stab(Hx) = x^{-1}Hx$

Group action is assumed to be conjugation action.

I found this to be only true if H is a normal subgroup. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you write down your argument? Otherwise my only answer can be "I don't know". We are talking about the right-multiplication action on cosets, aren't we?

Comment: Sorry I meant the action is conjugation action.

Comment: @W.Scott Do you mean that $G$ acts on $S$ by conjugation?

Comment: Yes, precisely. e.g. Stab(Hx) = {g in G | (g-inverse)H(g) = Hx}

Comment: @W.Scott Since you accepted the answer below, the action is right multiplication, not conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is confusion about the intended action. I suggest that the situation is this.

$G$ is a finite group, $H\leqslant G$, $S=\{Hx|x\in G\}$, with the action given by $Hx\mapsto Hxg$ for each $g\in G$.

Then 
$$
Hxg=Hx
\Leftrightarrow
Hxgx^{-1}=H
\Leftrightarrow
xgx^{-1}\in H
\Leftrightarrow
g\in x^{-1}Hx,
$$
so that $\text{Stab}(Hx)=x^{-1}Hx$.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my life!

Comment: I think that the notation $\alpha^g$ for group actions (which is great) can lead to its own confusions.